# Image bimap does not fit into canvas exactly?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to fit my taken photo bitmap nicely into a canvas for painting however, the canvas always omit a large part of the bitmap.

I'm using this [CanvasView API from GitHub](https://github.com/Korilakkuma/CanvasView) that extends view with the following XML

```
<com.android.graphics.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/canvasView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The problem comes when using the bitmap from another GitHub API code from [here](https://github.com/kosalgeek/PhotoUtil/blob/master/README.md#to-get-a-bitmap) that uses this statement:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(width, height).getBitmap();
```

Thereafter, I will use the above bitmap to import into the canvas for drawing: `this.canvasView.drawBitmap(bitmap);`

Within the .drawBitmap() API thus, its not the usual drawBitmap(bitmap,width,height, paint);

```
public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.invalidate();
    }
```

Tried these 2 methods to try solve the issue but to no avail or am i exploring the wrong direction? Or is there intermittent steps/code I've missed out in between? Thanks for any helped rendered!

```
canvasView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
width = canvasView.getMeasuredWidth();
height = canvasView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

and

```
canvasView.post( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int width  = canvasView.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = canvasView.getMeasuredHeight(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Are the bitmap dimensions correct, as requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would see if the bitmap was the expected size after requesting it, debug it, or log the dimensions of it.

Looking at the code for that repo, I don't think `requestSize` does what you think it should.

In the [repo](https://github.com/kosalgeek/PhotoUtil/blob/master/PhotoUtil/app/src/main/java/com/kosalgeek/android/photoutil/ImageLoader.java) for that library, there is a comment around request size:

```
// Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
// height and width larger than the requested height and width.
```

Now that is not what you are expecting I bet.

I'd never use a little, unpopular, library for such simple stuff, it's adding no value, it's better to be in control and the same goes for the other library. Also because they are unpopular, you won't find much help on here or anywhere else, because people don't have experience of using them.

Comment: If i had to use that bitmap as it is because changing that statement i've have to revamp a large part of my codes. It it possible to tweet that bitmap as it is to fit it into the canvas?

Comment: tweet? no I don't recommend going via twitter api!

Comment: oh sorry for my poor command of English. I mean "work around" that existing bitmap received to fit into canvas?

Comment: oh, tweak, sorry I knew what you meant! yes, just google resizing a bitmap in android I'm sure you'll find lots of help.

Comment: hi I've added Bitmap scaledbitmap = bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true); however, error stated that width and height must be > 0. Did i wrongly code the way i get width and height of my canvas?

Comment: Maybe, I see you get the size in a runnable, don't know why or what you do with them after that. Why don't you just do this `width = canvasView.getMeasuredWidth()` just before that call.

Comment: that worked Thanks. However, i found scaling to be quite damaging to the image quality thus found alternative https://adilatwork.blogspot.sg/2012/10/android-how-to-scale-bitmap-and-retain.html Its does help a bit but is there another way to adjust the image quality on canvas to look similar to the effect of imageview object's .setImageBitmap() class where its more dynamic and natural looking?

Comment: This is getting quite far from the original question. Ask a new one.

Comment: Hi I have posted to the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486117/how-to-edit-the-code-to-act-as-imageview-instead-of-view